# GAS error, listbox field displays "function addKeyPressHandler() {/* */}" instead of list

Tags: google-apps-script, listbox

I just created this form and my first listbox works well, and notes box works well but second listbox is full of junk, non of which is found in the code? 
starting with :
 "function addKeyPressHandler() {/* */}" 
then on to: mousedown, stylePrimary etc
any clue why?

```
var LOCATION = ['Select a Location','A Res','B Res','C Res','D Res','MNT','OSB','TWB','VP','VM','SITE DEV']
var ISSUETYPE = ['Select an ISSUE TYPE','Poor Workmanship','Lack of Training','Not Per Plans','Not Per Code','Not Per Spec','Plan Conflict']
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's hard to say exactly why without seeing more of your code, the "junk" you describe will show up when you are looping over and displaying properties of an object.  You're seeing the functions attached to that object.

So check the code you are using to generate the select options on the problematic listbox, it's probably a typo, or perhaps you've inadvertently re-used a variable name and assigned an object too it, or maybe you have an un-quoted string that matches the name of some object.